# How do I use the input from a \prompt in a conditional (\if)?

Tags: psql

Let's say I get value from a prompt?

```
\prompt 'Write [Yes] or [No]\n' store
```

Which does this,

```
Write [Yes] or [No]
Yes
```

I can verify I have that works,

```
\echo :store
Yes
```

But, I can't get it to work with `\if`

```
\if :store='Yes'
unrecognized value "Yes=Yes" for "\if expression": Boolean expected
```

`\prompt`'s doc don't say much on this

> `\prompt [ text ] name` Prompts the user to supply text, which is assigned to the variable name. An optional prompt string, text, can be specified. (For multiword prompts, surround the text with single quotes.)
>
> By default, \prompt uses the terminal for input and output. However, if the -f command line switch was used, \prompt uses standard input and standard output.

Comment: As far as I understand [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) "*read their argument(s) and evaluate them as a boolean expression*" you can only use `\if :store` and that requires `store` to contain something that can be converted to a boolean. Plus the manual also says: "*A conditional block must begin with an `\if` and end with an `\endif`*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name someone figured it out. =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can accomplish this using using `\gset` to coerce the variable into a boolean which `\if` can use,

```
$ cat if_prompt.sql 
\prompt 'enter abc here: ' x
select ('abc' = :'x') as is_abc \gset
\if :is_abc
  \echo you can read
\else
  \echo you are illiterate or impertinent
\endif
```

Testing it,

```
$ psql test -f if_prompt.sql 
enter abc here: abc
you can read

$ psql test -f if_prompt.sql 
enter abc here: 123
you are illiterate or impertinent
```